# How to stop mesh to crop into other mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

Hello, I want my chain to "lay" on the bottle, if I put it too close it cuts through, but if I move it then it looks like it is not lying on the bottle. How can I make it like it is laying on, I use bezier curve to move it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to do it manually, moving the curve's vertices. Note that you can tilt the vertices with Ctrl T (or tweaking the Tilt value in the N panel), it may help

Comment: I added more subdivisions and vertices, and that tip helped me to "lay" the chain better. Thanks!